# Rule based scipy sparse dot product

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have one large scipy `csr_matrix` and want to calculate `matrix.dot(matrix.T)`. However, I do not need every single dot product, but rather only those based on some rules. For eample, as specified by another binary matrix that has nonzero elements for those rows/columns that should be calculated. For eample, if `rules[0,10]=1` then, the dot product between row 0 and row 10 should be determined. These rules could of course also be represented by some other data structure.

A simple solution would be to manually loop through the rules and then slice according rows/columns and determine the dot product. This does not seem to be the best solution to me, specifically as slicing is also quite expensive with sparse matrices. Maybe, someone has a better idea about how to approach this.

Comment: Dot product is one of the fastest operations.  Use that, if possible, to select values that you want to keep or use.

Comment: Well, my dot product is quite large which is why I am looking for another solution.

Comment: Are you just trying to save time, or do those unnecessary products mess up the values?

Comment: A demonstration with a small dense array would help the conversation.  Maybe even do time tests.  Indexing and iteration on sparse matrices is slower than the equivalent dense operations, even if you work directly with the underlying arrays.  So if you can't get a speed up with dense arrays I don't see how you can get it with sparse ones.

Comment: There is no option of transferring it to dense arrays due to memory limitations. That's why I am looking for a sparse solution.